# clicking outside the div inside div should be close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i tried this code to open the inner div and close the div. but i have the problem when i click outside the div then it is not close. just i need help in it when i click outside the div then also inner div should be close.

here is the code:

```
<div class="userNameBox">prashant birajdar
    <div class="profile" style="display:none" tabindex="-1">
       here is the code.        
    </div>
</div>
```

here is js code

```
$( ".userNameBox" ).click(function() {
  $( ".profile" ).toggle( "slow" );
});
```

and here is jsfiddel http://jsfiddle.net/prashantbirajdar123/tY2vU/

Comment: So you want clicks outside of `.userNameBox` to close `.profile`?

Comment: Your code captures clicks INSIDE the div - you have no handler for the outside (unless you have it somewhere else in the code).

Comment: outside means document...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution in my opinion is to add an event on the body that will hide the profile on click, and in you userNameBox function stop the event propagation.

```
$( ".userNameBox" ).click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $( ".profile" ).toggle( "slow" );
});

$(document).click(function(e){
  $( ".profile" ).hide( "slow" );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Listen on the body and see where the click came from

```
$(document).click(function(evt) {
  if($(evt.target).closest(".userNameBox").length===0 && $(".profile").is(":visible")) {
      $(".profile").slideUp( "slow" );
  }
});
```